# Is there a fix for the won't-restart won't-reboot won't-logout bug in 11.10

Tags: unity, shutdown, logout

Since I upgraded to 11.10, neither the "shutdown" (for shutdown or restart) nor the "logout" options in the upper-right-corner menu work. They simply do nothing.

While waiting for Ubuntu to release a fix, is there something I can do to have them work again?

My current workaround for rebooting or shutting down is to open a terminal and type "shutdown -r now" or "shutdown -h now", which work. Is there a similar workaround for logging out?

Anyway I'm also looking for a real fix that would make the shutdown/logout options in the menu work.

Hibernate and suspend do work, by the way.

Comment: Quicker commands for shutting down are `reboot` and `poweroff`.

Comment: Please follow this bug on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-session/+bug/891083)

Comment: Closed as off-topic? In which way exactly does this not relate to Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

this also happens to me, here is my bug report of the issue: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-session/+bug/891083

Answer (score 0):

As workarounds for logging out, here are several possible approaches:

- Go to the keyboard settings and enable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to kill the X server.
- Run `sudo service lightdm restart`
- Run `sudo killall X`

Note that--as with your workarounds--**these workarounds are risky.** They will kill the X server immediately without giving the running programs a chance to ask the user to save. The shutdown and reboot commands you mentioned are marginally safer.